# creating simple countdown timer with pause functionality in Angular2

Tags: angular

I am currently working on an Ionic2 project. It a question/answer page.

I have to create a simple countdown timer with pause/resume functionality.

Scenario is, on page load, countdown timer will start with 40 minutes. On every passing minutes(60 seconds) timer will reduce 1 minute. But if user press the pause button the timer will pause, and whenever the user press resume button the timer will start from previous paused value.

Please help as I cant figure out how to achieve this.

Comment: Can you post of the code you have tried either in plunkr or any online editor? so that we can look into.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is very much possible. Please check these AngularJS timer examples:

https://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/examples.html#/angularjs-single-timer-demo

I would recommend some api where you can create your own "Timer" object like the Jquery timer or Angular Timer.

In Angular 2  you could use Observable.timer and described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35813310/how-to-create-timer-in-angular2).

You could also check out [ng2-simple-timer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-simple-timer) or [ng2-timer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-timer).

Good luck!