# C3.js - this.chart.load is not a function - angular 2 and Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js, angular2-template, c3.js

I am generating chart using c3. I am accessing Rest API in the c3 chart to load the JSON data. I referred this example http://c3js.org/samples/data_load.html
I am trying to load the chart dynamically using load function which gives me

> Runtime Error this.chart.load is not a function

```
private chart: any;
this.chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        url: '/api/systemvalues',
        type: 'line'
    }
});
setTimeout(function () {
    this.chart.load({
        url: '/api/systemvalues'
    });
}, 1000);
```

These are the versions used:

```
 @angular/core": "2.4.10", 
 "c3": "^0.4.11", 
 "d3": "^3.5.17", 
 "typescript": "2.2.2"
```

Answer (score 2):

call the `setTimeout` using `()=>` instead `function(){`

```
private chart: any;
this.chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        url: '/api/systemvalues',
        type: 'line'
    }
});
setTimeout(()=>{
    this.chart.load({
        url: '/api/systemvalues'
    });
}, 1000);
```

**OR**

assign `this` to variable and use that variable inside a constructor and call the `setTimeout` function

```
private chart: any;
this.chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        url: '/api/systemvalues',
        type: 'line'
    }
});
constructor(){
  var vm = this;

  setTimeout(function () {
    vm.chart.load({
        url: '/api/systemvalues'
    });
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..It worked. Now I am not getting that error

Comment: This solution did not work `setTimeout(()=>{
    this.chart.load({
        url: '/api/systemvalues'
    });
}, 1000);`

Comment: what about the other one

Comment: The other one did not show any error. But the chart is not getting updated dynamically. I have to refresh manually to see the new values on the chart.

Comment: note that content of the timeout only executes once after 1 second. After that it will not execute

Comment: Okay Thanks. Is it possible to load or refresh for every 5 minutes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35813310/how-to-create-timer-in-angular2