# setInterval and update data

Tags: typescript, angular

How i can update my API (get) with this function `setInterval()`

I have this this get func.:

```
getServices(){
    return this._http.get(this._url)
                    .map(res => res.json());
}
```

And i would to refresh my data (get json data) every 1 second

I found this example, but this function only show logs every  one second, and how update my API with get?

```
 setInterval(function (getServices) {
             console.log("Test")
         }, 1000)
```

Comment: Please provide more information. To me it's entirely unclear what the desired behavior should be.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer i update my question

Comment: What does "How i can update my API" mean. I don't get what you try to accomplish.

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35316583/angular2-http-at-an-interval

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer i would refresh data on the page, but not reload page. my data is json from gerServices()

Comment: This is not enough information. I'd suggest you create a Plunker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should probably be something like:

```
setInterval(() => {
    this. getServices();
    console.log("Test")
}, 1000);
```

But as your question is not very clear, it's hard to know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean that you have a function getServices which you want to call every second and do something with the result.

This is how you can do this:

```
setInterval(() => {
    let result = getServices();
    console.log(result);
}, 1000)
```

[Playground with working example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Test%20%7B%0D%0A%09getServices()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%2F%2Freturn%20this._http.get(this._url)%0D%0A%09%09%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.map(res%20%3D%3E%20res.json())%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%09return%20%22result%22%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20test%20%3D%20new%20Test()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AsetInterval(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09let%20result%20%3D%20test.getServices()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(result)%3B%0D%0A%7D%2C%201000)) - Run and open console (F12), you will see data is being added to console every second.