# How to call function in Angular every 10 seconds

Tags: angular, typescript

How can you call Observable function to download data from server every 10 seconds?

My App service

```
    getDevices (): Observable<Device[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.deviceUrl)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

My AppComponent

```
ngOnInit():void {
    this.getData();
    this.getLastDeviceInterior();
    this.getOutDevice();
    this.getSetings();
  }

  getData()
  {
    this.dataService.getDevices().subscribe( devices => this.devices = devices,
      error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }
```

Comment: consider using an $interval

Comment: Using setInterval().  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

Comment: Already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35316583/angular2-http-at-an-interval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use setInterval if using Angular

```
  getData()
  {
      setInterval(() => {
           this.dataService.getDevices().subscribe( devices => this.devices = devices,
           error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
       }, 10);
  }
```

OR

```
   setInterval(() => {
       this.getData();
   }, 10);
```

Comment: settimeout runs once after the set timeout.  setinterval runs many times according to your intervals.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696692/setinterval-vs-settimeout

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in javascript to call something every x milliseconds:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp