# Set Timer For HTTP request

Tags: angularjs, angular

Is there a possible way for me to set a timer for the client side to periodically make a request to the server automatically?

For example

```
Polling(){

this.http.makeRequestEvery1min(){

subscribe(data => {

)
}
//request should be every sent every 1 minute 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Rx.Observable.interval(60*1000).
  switchMap(x=> http.getSomething())
  .subscribe(x=>console.log(x))
```

Comment: This is the cleanest way of going about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript's setInterval function inside ngOnInit.

setInterval(function(){
// Do Something }, 3000)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the interval function.

```
.controller
( 'sampleController',['$scope','$interval', function ($scope, $interval) {


       function Polling(){

          //Write your http request here.
      }


var interval = 1000; //in milliseconds

var intervalPromise = $interval(polling, 1000); 


//To Kill the interval function on page closure or route change

$scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        if (angular.isDefined(intervalPromise)) {
            $interval.cancel(intervalPromise);
        }
    });

}]);
```

Comment: have look at this stackoverflow post for example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35316583/angular2-http-at-an-interval