# Angular 2: How to refresh entire page automatically on after some time

Tags: html, angular, components

I am trying to code in Angular to such that it reloads entire HTML page automatically after 10 seconds.

Please help how to do it, i am new to Angular 2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `setTimout()` and call the `ngOnInit()`

Comment: Could you elaborate on the purpose for this? Do you want to reload the entire page? Or just the data for the page? The solution is different depending on which you require.

Comment: @Deorahk yes,In html page i am having calendar which contain events,once user clicked on that it ,it should block for 10 minutes and call the services again after 10 minutes and reload.

Comment: Check out the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35316583/angular2-http-at-an-interval It goes into detail on how to set up a timer for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 http at an interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35316583/angular2-http-at-an-interval)

Answer (score 2):

**you have two choices:**

1- Using ng2-simple-timer-example:

Angular 2 has a simple component that handle timer: ng2-simple-timer-example

[Github Link](https://github.com/J-Siu/ng2-simple-timer-example)

This plunker shows the result:

[Online Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/HaTd8q/)

2- setTimout:

As @Araivnd mentions you can using ngOnInit(angular calls ngOnInit after creating the component) and setTimout as following:

```
ngOnInit(){
    setTimeout(function(){
          //code here
        },10000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
setTimeout(
function(){ 
location.reload(); 
}, 10000);
```