# How send request via interval operator?

Tags: angular, http, rxjs

I try send http-request. I use angular 2 and rxjs library. I need send a request with a period of 5 seconds.

At first i import operator and use it follow:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
// import { interval } from 'rxjs/observable/interval';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';

@Injectable()
export class TasksService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { };
  getUserTasks(userId): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.interval(5000).get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/app_tasks/user_tasks?user_id=' + userId);
  };
}
```

Secondly i subscribe in component:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  let userId = 1;
  this.getUserTasks(userId);
}

private getUserTasks(userId): void {  
  this.tasksService.getUserTasks(userId).subscribe(
    data => {   
      this.userTasks = JSON.parse(data);                 
      console.log('userTasks', this.userTasks);
    }
  )
};
```

But consoe display follow error message:

> ERROR in src/app/services/tasks.service.ts(16,21): error TS2339:
>   Property 'interval' does not exist on type 'HttpClient'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Interval` is a creator function for an Observable, not HttpClient. I would try the following:

```
Observable.interval(5000)
  .switchMap(_ => this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/app_tasks/user_tasks?user_id=' + userId)
```

By using `.switchMap` you will abandon the previous http.get result if a new interval is hit before your previous request returns (5 seconds, hope that does not happen).

Answer (score 0):

I think on Angular 4+ you should use `IntervalObservable` for this.
You can read more about version changes on this old question ([Angular2+ http at an interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35316583/angular2-http-at-an-interval)) or use right answer @Ploppy https://stackoverflow.com/a/40285206/5319874

Answer (score 0):

According to accepted answer. `switchMap` will not be the best idea if request takes more than 5 seconds. As alternative I'd rather suggest `exhaustMap`:

```
Observable.interval(5000)
 .exhaustMap(_ => this.http.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/app_tasks/user_tasks?user_id=${userId}`)
```

It will not cancel pending request after 5 seconds but ignore any request until pending request either fails or returns value. But it depends on your case.